# Mp3 duration doubling after mutagen.py edits in iTunes only

Tags: python, mp3, itunes, mutagen, itunesartwork

I am trying to create a python code that edits a mp3's info and adds the title, artist, and album. This will make it so that when it's opened in iTunes, I don't have to manually add the info to the song. After I open the mp3 file in iTunes, the duration of the mp3 that iTunes shows has doubled (to 7:07), while the duration of the mp3 file in File Explorer and VLC stays the same (3:39). I am 90% sure that the length doubles after mutagen(the module that edits the file) does its work. But it could also be iTunes problem, I am not sure. Please provide feedback, thank you!

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250712483 - This thread says that after editing the artwork of a song, track times are extended.

Code right now:

```
def info_of_mp3(dictionary_of_info, filenamefull):
    from mutagen.id3 import ID3, TIT2, TPE2, TALB, TPE1, TYER, TDAT, TRCK, TCON, TORY, TPUB, USLT
    dictionary_of_info = {   # example info input
    "TIT2":"Idli Chutney",  #TITLE
    "TPE1":"Sean Roldan",  #ARTIST
    "TALB":"None"  #ALBUM
}
    filenamefull = "Sean Roldan - Idli Chutney.mp3"  #example filename input
    SAVE_PATH = "C:/directions/to/my/folder"
    audio = ID3(SAVE_PATH+"/"+filenamefull)
    
    audio.add(TIT2(encoding=3, text = dictionary_of_info["TIT2"]))    #TITLE
    audio.add(TPE1(encoding=3, text = dictionary_of_info["TPE1"]))    #ARTIST
    audio.add(TALB(encoding=3, text = dictionary_of_info["TALB"]))    #ALBUM

    audio.save(v2_version=3)
```

File Explorer length:
[File Explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DzWqh.png)

iTunes length:
[iTunes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/foU0e.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to convert to AAC version on iTunes. This also makes a copy of the song, so you can delete the original.